# New Motherboard, Computer not Producing Display or Shutting Off

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure

My old motherboard recently died (atleast, I think it did), and I bought a new one. I just set it all up, but when I turn it on, the monitor doesn't pick up any signal, and I can't turn it off without using the power supply switch. Everything is running inside, all the lights work, etc. I removed everything except the motherboard and the CPU, and I get the same problem. Is it the CPU thats broken, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you hold the power button for a couple of seconds it might power off the system.

The CPU *could* be broken, of course, but in my experience, it is very uncommon as compared to other parts, the PSU in particular, which produces the same symptoms and is present even in your minimal test. That would be my first test, based on probability.

Comment: Holding the power button down does not turn off the system. I should mentioned that the CPU pins were bent a little, but it still fit in the slot. When my old motherboard died, I did not have these symptoms, it is only with the new one. So I'm unsure if it is the PSU, but I'll do some tests.

Comment: The pins on your CPU being bent likely means you damaged the CPU itself. Those pins are very fragile.  The only way to bend them is to insert the cpu into the slot the wrong way.

Comment: They got bent when I removed the CPU. I pushed them back and it fit in. Does that mean that's the problem? Looking at the CPU now, I can't even tell which ones got bent.

Comment: The pins very well may be damaged at the point of connection to the chip - if they're no longer connected well the whole thing could go kablooey.  This certainly sounds likeliest - if the motherboard, CPU, and power supply are working properly, *at a minimum you should get error beeps if you try to boot it without any RAM installed*.  Since you say you didn't, and given the statement about the pins, I assume it is the CPU.

Comment: CPU pins that have been bent could very well be the problem. You could try your luck with another PSU first (since it is cheaper, and thus could be worth a shot to look at), but with the information on the bent CPU pins, I would no longer say that the PSU failing is much more likely than the CPU failing. But you said the old computer just died, and that was before the pins got bent, I suspect, so I still wouldn't rule out the PSU (at least as the original problem).

Comment: Ok, thank you. A this point, replacing the entire thing doesn't seem like that bad of an idea! But it was time for an upgrade anyway :) I tried with a PSU from my other computer and it still didn't work.